# Website dose not mobilize of phones or tablets. But Desktop yes...?

Tags: mobile, web

I used Google Material Design Lite to build my website but it won't mobilize... I did everything right and it works fine on the computer even when the Browser is shrunken down to a phone or tablet size. It mobilizes the site on there when the Browser is shrunked but not phones or tablets. I really need help fixing the issues with the site not reading the phone or tablet as smaller screens. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line to your html's `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`